# Error "This app can't run on your pc" when i run .exe from win10 Home

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and from my PC (MAC) i have created 3 builds of my project (1-MAC, 2-Windows x86_64, 3-WebGL)

I state that my version of Unity Hub is 2.4.2 and my Unity version is 2019.4.18f1

When i start my game on mac everything works fine (obviously starting the build for mac), later I put the x86_64 windows build in a compressed folder and then transferred it into a USB, to try the game from another pc (win 10 PRO). In this PC the same version of unity was already present.

So far, so good.

The problem starts when I take the same USB with the same files, which, as previously said on win10 pro work, I put them on a win10 home (32 bit) and when I try to start the .exe it gives me this error "This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher "

Looking on the internet I tried to get around the problem they change the local settings policy, but the result is the same :(

These are the files inside my compressed folder

[image: comp]

And these are my build settings

[image: sett]

I thank whoever will be able to help me and I apologize for my bad English

Comment: Check if some dlls in your project has dependency for x64 bit systems. Your target can be  for both x86 and x64 but if one of your assemblies have dependency for x64 only, your target should be x64 or you should change that dependency.

Comment: Finally I've decided to use webGL, thus solving my problems. Thank you @SeLeCtRa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say your other PC is 32 bit!

That's your issue!

You are building for the `Architecture`

`x86_64` => 64-bit CPU

It does **not** mean 32 or 64 bit.

To run it on a 32 bit system you have to build for `x86` instead.

See [Unity Manual - PC, Mac & Linux Standalone build settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettingsStandalone.html)

[image]